# Browsing cached pages with no internet connection

Tags: firefox, internet, browser-cache

Back in the early days of the Internet, when 56K modems were considered state-of-the-art, when the modem was disconnected I could still freely browse the pages that I recently visited because they were kept in the browser's cache.

Now, I cannot find this option, at least not in Firefox.

The Internet was disconnected due to a storm, and I tried to open a Wikipedia page I visited just yesterday, but Firefox could not open it.

I tried "File -> Offline mode", but this didn't help: I got a page showing the message "Firefox is currently in offline mode and can't browse the Web."

Is there a way to make Firefox automatically cache pages I visit, so that I can visit them again without Internet connection?

Comment: Hopefully you didn't shut down/reboot the system while Firefox was open (or do some other nasty thing causing Firefox to crash or terminate abruptly)? AFAIK Firefox loses the whole cache if something like that happens; also, some entries may disappear if you close and reopen Firefox (but I don't think that would happen for Wikipedia pages).

Answer (score -1):

Offline mode in the firefox  is very useful when you need to read the stored webpage instead of downloading the page by using the saved page.It would store the snap of the page you open when there is network connection so when you mark as offline.You would be able to open the page alone but if you redirect it would ask for network connection.

Comment: The author indicated offline mode didn't work for them.

Comment: Not true, because Firefox even 'remembers' most of the redirections too (AFAIK it's true for Wikipedia).